# NewRelic Java API and Transaction boundaries

Tags: java, api, newrelic

I want to monitor a critical part of our Java Application (Glassfish v3.1.2 JSF2 application).
I want to track a specific function call as a new transaction. This method can be called within the "/Faces Servlet" or any other JAX-RS transactions.

The @Trace annotation seems to be perfect for my case but reading the doc it is not clear if it supports nested transactions (like the REQUIRES_NEW J2EE transaction semantic).

Here is the method I want to track

```java
@Trace(dispatcher=true, matricName="Internal/Query")
public void query(Query q) {
       long st = -System.currentTimeMillis();
       // do my stuff
       st += System.currentTimeMillis();
       NewRelic.addCustomParameter("Client", q.getClient());
       // Add useful parameters
       NewRelic.recordResponseTimeMetric("Internal/Query/queryTime", st); // Is this needed?
}
```

And for example a JAX-RS WS like this :

```java
@GET
public Response wsquery(...) { // <- Start NewRelic Transaction T1
       myBean.query(q1); // <- Start nested Transaction T1.1
       myBean.query(q2); // <- Start nested Transaction T1.2
}
```

Will I Have 3 transactions tracked?
One for the JAX-RS call to *wsquery* and two for *Internal/Query*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of the information provided it's not certain exactly what you're going to get. I recommend giving it a test.  You can also bump up the logging level to the "finest" level and see exactly what is being instrumented.  If you run into issues beyond that contact us at http://support.newrelic.com

Comment: Thanks, yes it's not what I expected, in fact NewRelic Agent does not support nesting a transaction. If transaction exists it will just be renamed. If I call query multiple times my transaction parameters will simply be overwritten by the last call.

Comment: By "nesting" is the new transaction that is invoked by the other using the same process or thread?  If not, it's quite possible that we "lose scent of the trail" so to speak and that could prevent the agent from reporting.

Does this make sense?

Thanks,
Jeanie